# Can't pass data between tabBar views in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to pass data to other view on tabBar without performing a transition. But the variable I declared (named distance) turns nil even though I changed Its value.

First VC

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let vcToSend = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "listView") as! ListViewController
 vcToSend.distance = "abc"
```

ListViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var distance:String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = distance
    }
```

When I tried to print the value of distance, it prints "nil". I checked the names of Storyboard Id and VC. Why I can't pass the data ?

Edit : I tried same code at another View outside the tabBar and it worked, but I still couldn't figured out to do with a tabBar view.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple Human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/navigation-and-search/tab-bars), you should probably not be doing that.

In any case you would keep this behaviour, the tab bar component is responsible of the instantiation of the new view controller.
What you are doing is instantiating another, which is never shown.

What you can do is something similar to:

```swift
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is ListViewController })?.distance = 18
```